# out of memory when creating game field

Tags: c#

I get this error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Out of memory.
```

whenever after running this for a minute

```
using (var imageBuffer = new Bitmap(500, 300))
        {

            using (var graphicsObject = Graphics.FromImage(imageBuffer))
            {
                graphicsObject.Clear(Color.Azure);

                using (var boundryPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 10))
                {
                    graphicsObject.DrawRectangle(boundryPen, 0, 0, 500, 300);
                }

                g.DrawImage((Image)imageBuffer.Clone(), 80, 45); // error coming from this line
            }
        }
```

I am new to c#. I have tried to do g.dispose(), but it does not let me run the program.

Comment: is this whole statement in a loop? there by creating infinite clones?

Comment: Why are you using `Clone()`?

Comment: How can this be *running for a minute*?

Comment: @RustyH yes it gets redrawn multiple time

Comment: @siride its the only way I knew how to do it

Comment: @user3439558: you can just pass in the `imageBuffer` variable directly. I don't see why you need to add a `Clone()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Clone` on `imageBuffer`, you can draw it to the screen directly. Also, where is `g` coming from? That might be important if this code is in a loop.

Comment: In my opinion this does not answer the `OutOfMemoryException` problem.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: to be fair, there isn't enough info to truly answer the question. All the same, the OOM problem is not being helped by cloning images unnecessarily.

Comment: g is just `Graphics g` created to draw the board